# How do I see the Oracle execution plan in SQuirrel SQL?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to get the execution plan for Oracle (11) using SQuirreL SQL 3.6.

I can see an "Explain Plan" tab next to the "Results" tab but it's always empty.
When I clicked on it the first time, I got a dialog asking to create the `PLAN_TABLE` which worked but the table in the "Explain Plan" tab stays empty.

I tried to add `explain plan for` before my query but that gave me an `Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Comment: I don't have SQuirreL, but if it has an option to specify an existing plan table you should get it to use `sys.plan_table$`. This has been the standard for several Oracle releases now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way independent of your SQL client:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'yourTag' into   plan_table  FOR
select .... your query here ... from tab;
---    
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'yourTag','ALL'));
```

You get the complete execution plan as a result of the query.
The `PLAN_TABLE` must exists und your user must be granted to read and write to it.

sample output for the query

```
select * from dual where dummy = 'X';



Plan hash value: 272002086

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / DUAL@SEL$1

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - storage("DUMMY"='X')
       filter("DUMMY"='X')

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "DUMMY"[VARCHAR2,1]
```

Comment: You can omit the `statement_id` (including the `into   plan_table` for any modern Oracle version) and then use `FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(format => 'ALL'));`